# Ubuntu On VirtualBox (No Wireless Icon)

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on virtualbox software, and am trying to connect to the internet witch i can't, it doesn't even show a wireless icons. My original sys is Windows 10. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't expect a wireless icon. VirtualBox will emulate a wired network adapter.

Comment: Adding on to the previous comment, you do need to enable this network emulation in VirtualBox though, before it will work.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate but I wrote an answer addressing why VBox won't ever see wifi on that suggested possible duplicate.